# Sum up array first, then push into array loop solution

Tags: php, arrays

I had a problem with this particular code. The conditions are:

- When `$rows['Machine#']` is not in array, push in `$machineArr` array and unset the `$totalTimeArr` array.
- When `$rows['Machine#']` is in the array, push `$rows['TotalTime']` into `$totalTimeArr` array for addition.
- `$graphArr[]` should be updated (for `array_sum($totalTimeArr)`) first before push into array.
- only one `$graphArr[]` for each machine

I now have problems regarding the third condition. It does not calculate first, instead it pushes the first data input. I have tried using `do while` loop, putting `$graphArr[] = '["'.$rows['Machine#'].'",'.array_sum($totalTimeArr).']';` outside the `if else` loop, but this seems to be the closest I can get to what it's supposed to be. Other codes don't seem to have any problems and work well. Appreciate your recommendations/suggestions/assistance. Below is the code.

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($conn))
    {
        if(!(in_array($rows['Machine#'], $machineArr)))
        {
            unset($totalTimeArr);
            $machineArr[] = $rows['Machine#'];
            $totalTimeArr[] = $rows['TotalTime'];
            $graphArr[] = '["'.$rows['Machine#'].'",'.array_sum($totalTimeArr).']';
        }
        else if(in_array($rows['Machine#'], $machineArr))
        {
            $totalTimeArr[] = $rows['TotalTime'];
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I'm currently on this:

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($conn)) 
{
        $exists = false;
        if( in_array($rows['Machine#'], $machineArr) ) 
        { 
            $exists = true; 
        }

        $totalTimeArr[] = $rows['TotalTime'];
        if($exists === false) 
        {
            $totalTimeArr = array();
            $machineArr[] = $rows['Machine#'];
            $totalTimeArr[] = $rows['TotalTime'];
        }

        $graphArr[] = '["'.current($machineArr).'",'.array_sum($totalTimeArr).']';
        next($machineArr);
    }
```

The result:

```
Array ( [0] => ["09CS1", 1.4]
        [1] => ["08CS1", 1  ]
        [2] => ["06CS1", 1  ]
        [3] => [""     , 1.5]
        [4] => ["02CS2", 1  ]
        [5] => ["01CS2", 20 ]
        [6] => [""     , 40 ]
        [7] => ["01CS1", 1  ]
)
```

How do I remove `["", 1.5]` and `["", 40]`?

Below is the database:

[image: The database:]

Comment: The `unset($totalTimeArr)` looks a bit out of place there, i.e., you are appending to an array you've just unset.

Comment: does the connection work?

Comment: When you perform the `array_sum()` function there is only one element present, always, as you have just unset the present array and only added one element after that.

Comment: @RST - The solution I provided is based on the assumption that the logic flow is as the author intended.  Possibly, if not in the array, then the variable `$totalTimeArr` may be used outside of the loop ?

Comment: @apokryfos yes. I want to reuse it for each `$row['Machine#']`

Comment: if it helps, I actually intend to something like
`$graphArr[] = '["'.$machineArr[].'",'.array_sum($totalTimeArr).']';`
but I cant relate both the `$machineArr[]`.

Comment: Assume you have `n` results, and `in_array($rows['Machine#'], $machineArr)` is true for `n-2` results, but it's false for the (n-1)th result, you're going to only have a single element in `$totalTimeArr`. Is that what you need?

Comment: @apokryfos that is exactly the problem. haha. How do I avoid that? I've tried putting `$graphArr[] = '["'.$rows['Machine#'].'",'.array_sum($totalTimeArr).']';` outside the if..else loop, but I have problems with that as it also prints the value before the addition...

Comment: You need to specify the behaviour you need more clearly. Otherwise you'll be getting responses which don't really answer your question, because you haven't asked the right question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need to do, if you need a running sum for a specific type of a machine then do something like:

```
$totalTileArr = [];

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($conn)) {
    if (!isset($totalTileArr[$rows['Machine#']])) { 
        $totalTileArr[$rows['Machine#']] = [];
    }
    $totalTimeArr[$rows['Machine#']][] = $rows['TotalTime'];
    $graphArr[$rows['Machine#']] = '["' . $rows['Machine#'] . '",' . array_sum($totalTimeArr[$rows['Machine#']]) . ']';    
}
```

Comment: Close but almost sir. The result I get is this:

`Array ( [0] => ["09CS1",1.4] [1] => ["08CS1",1] [2] => ["06CS1",1] [3] => ["06CS1",1.5] [4] => ["02CS2",1] [5] => ["01CS2",20] [6] => ["01CS2",40] [7] => ["01CS1",1] )`

I want to remove the value before the addition, for example, for:
`[2] => ["06CS1",1] [3] => ["06CS1",1.5] `
I want to remove `[2] => ["06CS1",1]`.

Comment: Thanks sir, this solved the problem! Just needed an edits:

`$graphArr[]` to `$graphArr[$rows['Machine#]`

`$totalTileArr[$rows['Machine#']] = [];` to `$totalTileArr[$rows['Machine#']] = $rows['Machine#'];`

`$rows['Machine#']` to `$totalTileArr[$rows['Machine#']]`

Comment: I've made a change to `$graphArr[]` to make it `$graphArr[$rows['Machine#']]` and therefore only have it contain the latest sum for a given machine. This will make the array associative so if you need to the result to not be associative you'll need to add `$graphArr = array_values($graphArr)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified version of your code cleaned up

```
$machineArr = Array();
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($conn)) {
    $exists = false;
    if( in_array($rows['Machine#'], $machineArr) ) { $exists = true; }

    $totalTimeArr[] = $rows['TotalTime'];
    if($exists === false) {
        unset($totalTimeArr);
        $machineArr[] = $rows['Machine#'];
        $totalTimeArr[] = $rows['TotalTime'];
        $graphArr[] = '["'.$rows['Machine#'].'",'.array_sum($totalTimeArr).']';
    }
}
```

Converted the check into one `in_array()` search, then comparing using `===` bitwise operator to evaluate the condition. Also defined `$machineArr` as an `Array()` as the first check in your loop would always fail given that `$machineArr` was (presumably as I don't see the code prior to the while loop) undefined.